# How do I put a primary key constraint in BigQuery using the Python API?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am creating a BigQuery table using the Python API. I want to make `user_id` as the primary key. How do I add this constraint using the Python API?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
def create_table():
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("user_id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("first_name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("last_name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER")
    ]
    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
    table = client.create_table(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick search shows that [v3.11.4](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/v3.11.4/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py) doesn't support [`tableConstraints option`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#tableconstraints).

Subclass `bigquery.Table` and set the [`tableConstraints.primaryKey` field](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#tableconstraints) in the API request and you should have your table created with the desired constraints.

```py
class Table(bigquery.Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_primary_key(self, primary_key):
        if 'tableConstraints' not in self._properties:
            self._properties['tableConstraints'] = {}
        self._properties['tableConstraints']['primaryKey'] = primary_key        


def create_table(table_id,):
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("user_id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("first_name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("last_name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER")
    ]
    primary_key={"columns": ["user_id"]}
    table = Table(table_id, schema=schema)
    table.set_primary_key(primary_key)
    table = client.create_table(table)
```